# Similarity between two data sets or arrays

Tags: algorithm, correlation, similarity

Let's say I have a dataset that look like this:

```
{A:1, B:3, C:6, D:6}
```

I also have a list of other sets to compare my specific set:

```
{A:1, B:3, C:6, D:6},  
{A:2, B:3, C:6, D:6},  
{A:99, B:3, C:6, D:6},  
{A:5, B:1, C:6, D:9},  
{A:4, B:2, C:2, D:6}
```

My entries could be visualized as a Table (with four columns, A, B, C, D, and E).

How can I find the set with the most similarity?
For this example, row 1 is a perfect match and row 2 is a close second, while row 3 is quite far away.

I am thinking of calculating a simple delta, for example: `Abs(a1 - a2) +  Abs(b1 - b2) + etc` and perhaps get a [correlation value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient#Mathematical_properties) for the entries with the best deltas.

Is this a valid way?
And what is the name of this problem?

Comment: Are tge values A,B,C and D always constant?

Comment: I will always have the A B C D columns yes. their respected values will ofcourse change, but there will always be 4 "columns"

Comment: How would you solve this for thousands of records? Would you compare each with another and which DS to store in for efficently access?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Distance" or "similarity" could refer to this type of problem.

Simply calculating the sum of absolute difference, as you've done, should work fairly well. This is called the [**Manhattan distance**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry). In mathematical terms, it would be: `∑x ∈ (a,b,c,d) Abs(x1 - x2)`.

Although the best measure really depends on what behaviour you want.

**Ratio** could potentially be a better idea.

Consider something like `1000000, 5, 5, 5` vs `999995, 5, 5, 5` and `1000000, 0, 5, 5`.

According to the above formula, the first would have the same similarity to both the second and the third.

If this is not desired (as `999995` can be considered pretty close to `1000000`, while `0` can be thought of as quite far from `5`), you should divide by the maximum of the two when calculating each distance.

`∑x ∈ (a,b,c,d) [ Abs(x1 - x2) / max(x1, x2) ]`

This will put every number between 0 and 1, which is the percentage difference between the values.

This means that, for our above example, we'd consider `1000000, 5, 5, 5` and `999995, 5, 5, 5` to be very similar (since the above sum will be `|1000000-999995|/1000000 + 0 + 0 + 0 = 0.000005`) and `1000000, 5, 5, 5` and `1000000, 0, 5, 5` will be considered much more different (since the sum will be `|0+5|/5 + 0 + 0 + 0 = 1`).

**If negative values are possible**, the formula would need to be updated appropriately. You'd need to decide how you want to handle that based on the problem you're trying to solve. Should `10 to 0` be more or less different than (or equivalent to) `5 to -5`?

### Are elements interchangeable to any degree?

Consider something like `A=1, B=2, C=3, D=4` and `A=4, B=1, C=2, D=3`.

While every individual element has changed, the set still consists of `1, 2, 3, 4` and each element is simply shifted by 1 position (apart from `4`).

For some problems this isn't going to matter at all and the above wouldn't be all that different than going from `A=1, B=11, C=21, D=31` to `A=2, B=12, C=22, D=32`. For other problems it could be quite relevant though.

**For a sequence like a string or array**, the idea of inserting, deleting or shifting elements could make sense. If so, you would want to look at [edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance), a common one of which would be [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). You might also want to think about modifying this to consider how much individual values differ by (but this would not be trivial).

**For something like a set**, elements are interchangeable, but there wouldn't really be a strict order on the elements (`{1, 2, 3}` is the same as `{3, 1, 2}`). If this is the case, the simplest might be to sort the values and just use edit distance. You may also be able to loop through both at the same time in some way, which would allow you to more easily take the differences between values into account.

Comment: Why will divide help?

Comment: @Dukeling let' say if you have thousands maybe 10K entries that you have to find most similar items(say 5) for each entry among all 10K. Do you loop for all entries?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem reminds me of finding a [Hamming distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance).  Basically, the Hamming distance between two objects is the number of elements in one object that must be changed to make it match the other object.  There are similar measures as well ([Damerau–Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance), [Euclidean distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance), etc.).

You have a number of choices in how you implement this.  For instance, is the distance between {1,3,4} and {1,7,4} 1 (because one element changed) or 4 (because of the magnitude of the change)?  How you actually define the distance depends a lot on the context of your problem, and there's not necessarily a right answer.

Comment: It would be the magnitude

Comment: @Anders I would consider either the method you suggested, or the [Euclidean distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) then.

Comment: Thanks @Nathaniel, I will look into the Euclidean distance. I am not especially great at math, so it means a lot getting feedback on my proposed solution! :)