# Average between arrays of different length

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math, machine-learning, average

I'm trying to develop a sort of very simple machine learning example to recognize similarity between arrays.
For this reason I'm trying to calculate the average between 2 arrays with different length.

For example if I have:

```
array_1 = [0, 4, 5];
array_2 = [4, 2, 7];
```

The average is:

```
average_array = [2, 3, 6];
```

But how can I manage to calculate the average if I have the following situation:

```
array_1 = [0, 4, 5, 10, 7];
array_2 = [4, 2, 7];
```

As you can see the arrays have a different length.
Is there an algorithm that I can apply to solve this problems? 
Does anyone have an idea or some suggestion?

Of course I can consider the missing values of the second array as 0, and evaluate the average as, for example:

```
average_array = [2, 3, 6, 5, 3.5];
```

or  consider the values as "**null**" and have:

```
average_array = [2, 3, 6, 10, 7];
```

But are this two approach good?
Or there is something smarter?

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: you have only two arrays ?

Comment: what have you done ? where is you **code** ?

Comment: what language have you tried to achieve this goal ? `java` `c++` `python` `matlab` `r` ... ?

Comment: No I have more then 2 arrays but I just want to understand the idea/algorithm that best suits this problem. I think I'll use c++.

Comment: it is simple ,use `vector` instead of array, then you have the size of each of them, use a loop on all vectors , loop only changes the cursor from one vector to next, then by each index you have to check if vector range contains that index or not , and this is gonna calc average

Comment: maybe I didn't explained my self very well. I know how to calculate the average between arrays. The point is how can i calculate the average if the **vectors have different size**? What's the best mathematical approach to have the most precise value?

Comment: This isn't *really* a programming question, but more to do with how the average would be mathematically defined in this case.

Comment: that was answer to that question ... i wasn't explain how to calc average

Comment: you have problem with that explained comment :| look, you have to write a `for` statement that is a loop which count from zero to max of length in all vectors, which means you have to find the vector size that have the max length, after that you write another for, this for counts from zero to number of all vectors, now you have an `indice` for example `indice=4`, for each vector you know the `size`, here is the point ! if indice is larger than vector size, means you **skip** that vector and go to next vector and so on

Comment: this is obvious i think ... can you see any kind of vagueness in it ?

Comment: This seems opinion-based / too broad - this isn't so much an algorithmic problem as a "what result makes the most sense here" question, which is not something we can tell you and definitely doesn't have an objectively correct answer, you'll need to figure that out based on the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If after taking the the average of the arrays, you intend to take the **mod of the difference** of the array and the average array, then you are probably in the right direction if you will measure the dissimilarity by the magnitude of the difference.

But for arrays of different lengths I propose that you also take the index of extra elements in consideration.

For

```
array_1 = [0, 4, 5, 10, 7];
array_2 = [4, 2, 7];
```

average should be `average_array = [2, 3, 6, 6.5, 5.5];`

```
6.5 = (10 + 3(index) + 0(element) ) / 2
```

and

```
5.5 = (7 + 4(index) + 0(element))/2
```

**Reason** for taking index into consideration is that the **length** factor is also dealth with this approach. However this is just my 2 cents. May be there are better algorithms out there.

You should also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19815335/similarity-between-two-data-sets-or-arrays) post

Comment: Thanks! That's a quite interesting approach ;)

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, we really need more information on what you are trying to achieve.

> I'm trying to develop a sort of very simple machine learning example
>   to recognize similarity between arrays. For this reason I'm trying to
>   calculate the average between 2 arrays with different length.

Depending on your usecase, similarity might be defined completely differently.

For instance:

- if the array encodes sound-information you might want to measure similarity as "does this sound clip occur in this one" or "are the main frequencies (which would correspond to chords) the same"
- if the array encodes image information (properly DFT-ed and zig-zag-encoded) you might not care about the low frequencies (end of the array) and only measure the difference between the first few values of the array
- if the array encodes some kind of composition of elements (e.g. this essay contains keyword "matrix" 40 times, and keyword "SVM" 27 times) the difference in values might be very important.

General advice:

1. Think about what you're measuring
2. Decide what's important

But in general, have a look at smoothing algorithms. For instance Kneyser-Ney or Good-Turing smoothing. They explictly deal with comparing a vector of probabilities that may differ in length (in other words, have explicit zero entries)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good%E2%80%93Turing_frequency_estimation